# fill missing value base on other columns pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I want to fill missing value base on other columns in pandas.
Here is my table:

```
Gender     Married
Male       Yes
Male       Yes
Female     No
Female     No
Male       NaN
Female     NaN
```

I to fill missing value of Married field by if Gender is Male -> Married is Yes, else Married is No:

```
df['Married'].fillna(df[df['Married'].isnull()].apply(lambda x: 'Yes' if (df[df['Married'].isnull()]['Gender'] is 'Male') else 'No', axis=1), inplace=True)
```

But it was fail, I try a lot of way and I get nothing as my expectation.
I hope receive from all of you.

Comment: Hi @jpp thank for your answer, I can't see this post before I create my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) with `dictionary` only in filtered rows:

```
mask = df['Married'].isnull()
df.loc[mask, 'Married'] = df.loc[mask, 'Gender'].map({'Male':'Yes', 'Female':'No'})
print (df)
   Gender Married
0    Male     Yes
1    Male     Yes
2  Female      No
3  Female      No
4    Male     Yes
5  Female      No
```

Another solution with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
mask = df['Married'].isnull()
df.loc[mask, 'Married'] = np.where(df.loc[mask, 'Gender']  == 'Male', 'Yes','No')
print (df)
   Gender Married
0    Male     Yes
1    Male     Yes
2  Female      No
3  Female      No
4    Male     Yes
5  Female      No
```

Another solution with [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) of mapped `Series`:

```
df['Married'] = df['Married'].fillna(df['Gender'].map({'Male':'Yes', 'Female':'No'}))
```

Comment: Hi @jezrael, In the table with a lot of value, Gender Male also has No in Married but mode(Gender=Male) is Yes, so I want to fill NaN for Male is Yes and I don't want to modify data has value already. My explain is clear for you?

Comment: @HuyTruong - Sure, all 3 new solutions do it.

Comment: thank you so much, it work for me, I save a lot of time.

Comment: I have done it. Once again, thank you

Comment: Hi @jezrael, I have once more question, can you help me?

Comment: @HuyTruong - Sure, no problem.

Comment: I want to statistics value of one field base on some other field. Ex:
Field I want to collect: Dependent. 
Three fields index=[Gender, Married, Education]

Comment: @HuyTruong - Sorry, not understand.

Comment: Gender     Married     Education     Dependent
Male         No             Graduated    0
Female     Yes            Not Gra        1
Female     No             Graduated    0
Male         No             Graduated    1
Male         No             Graduated    NaN

I want to collect Dependent value with 3 field remain. Sorry I don't know how to create table

Comment: @HuyTruong - Is possible edit question - sample data with expected output? Because bad format of data in comemnts.

Comment: Hi @jezrael, here is [link data](https://imgur.com/1wbBOR1). I want to statistics Dependent value like that

Comment: Hi @jezrael, this is my new image for clearly [data](https://imgur.com/Jjn5lGG).

Comment: I am not statistics man, what is x value in last column?

Comment: I have uploaded new image, example: Male -> No -> Graduated -> Dependent: 1, Male -> Yes-> Graduated -> Dependent: 0, Male -> No -> NOt Gra -> Dependent: 0 etc ..

Comment: Sorry, simple to say that I want to sum Dependent value and create table like image. One more thing is count most Dependent value appear by mode() function and create the same table. My English is not good, if it not clear I will try more